# PgfPlots Vertical Asymptotes Are Cut Short

Tags: pgfplots

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
        \begin{axis}[ylabel=Y-Axis, xlabel=X-Axis, xmin=0.000, xmax=0.9, ymin=0, ymax=12, clip=false, yticklabel pos=right, ylabel near ticks]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,3,5,10}{
            \addplot[mark=none, domain=0.000:0.9, thick] {-ln(x/#1^2)/ln(#1)}; %Varying R values
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

yields the following graph

[image: Graph in which the plots do not make it to the X-axis]

Mathematically, these lines should extend to infinity when they reach x=0 at the left-hand side of the box.

What is the "best way" to get these lines close to the edge of the box or otherwise fill them in so they are not cut-off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use the `samples` option to `addplot` and increase the number:

```
\addplot[mark=none, domain=0.000:0.9, thick,samples=40] {-ln(x/#1^2)/ln(#1)} node [pos=0,left] {$R=#1$}; %Varying R values
```

here `40`  is just a wild guess.

Edit, actually a sample value of `500` is probably more what you want as `40` doesn't give you anything that different.

with a sample value of `500` you get this:

[image: plot using the <code>sample=500</code> solution]

Edit2:
Following @Jake suggestion, you can indeed use the `samples at` option to `addplot` to specify the intervals in x values which need more definition/samples. In this particular case, `samples at={0.001,0.002,...,0.01,0.02,...,0.9}` gives you a sample every 0.001 between 0.001 and 0.01 and a sample of 0.01 between 0.01 and 0.9. This is of course a manual setting and will have to be adapted to your different plots but in this case it works particularly well. In addition the `smooth` option with get rid of most of the raggedness of the plot:

[image: plotting using the <code>sample at={}, smooth</code> solution]

The advantage of the `samples=500` solution is that it is fairly generic across plots but it does require a lot more calculations which add to compilation time but may be the best solution if you are plotting things which varies a lot across the entire x range (`tan(x)` for example).

Comment: For problematic functions like this, I find the `samples at` feature quite useful, which allows you to specify sampling points explicitly. You can mix list and `...` notation, so in this case you could say something like `samples at={0.001,0.002,...,0.01,0.02,...,0.9}`, which would plot the function with about 60 samples, with a higher sampling density near the start.

Comment: Indeed that is probably better in general and will be much faster to compile. Although the end result isn't as smooth looking

Comment: You can add `smooth` to the `\addplot` options to smooth out the corners. While mathematically not exact, the result should be accurate enough for most purposes.

Comment: Ah indeed, learn new things every day!

Comment: @ArTourter, your answer had several syntactic errors in the material you included from Jake's comment. I've had to un-accept it pending resolution of those problems. (I've submitted edits.)

Comment: @richard, you are indeed correct. I had not copy/pasted my code but simply retyped it, albeit badly. Sorry about this. Alan Nunn has accepted your edits before I had the time to.